# Image not being dragged correctly when zoomed in

Tags: javascript, vue.js, zooming, drag, getboundingclientrect

I am encountering issues with the function provided below. When an image is zoomed in, it becomes possible to drag beyond its bounds. This issue results in a gap between the image and its container, and this gap increases as the image scale increases.

It appears that the `getBoundingClientRect` method is accurately capturing the updated dimensions of the image as it scales. Despite this, the cause of the problem remains.

Any suggestions for this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
dragMove(event) {
    if (this.isDragging && this.imageScale > this.minZoom) {
        const containerRect = this.$refs.croquisContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
        const imageRect = this.$refs.croquisImage.getBoundingClientRect();
    
        const maxOffsetX = (imageRect.width - containerRect.width) / 2;
        const maxOffsetY = (imageRect.height - containerRect.height) / 2;
    
        const deltaX = event.clientX - this.lastX;
        const deltaY = event.clientY - this.lastY;
    
        const newOffsetX = this.offsetX + deltaX;
        const newOffsetY = this.offsetY + deltaY;
    
        this.offsetX = Math.max(Math.min(newOffsetX, maxOffsetX), -maxOffsetX);
        this.offsetY = Math.max(Math.min(newOffsetY, maxOffsetY), -maxOffsetY);
    
        this.lastX = event.clientX;
        this.lastY = event.clientY;
    }
}
```

*JSFiddle:* https://jsfiddle.net/n4d7txwy/

**UPDATE**

This solves the question

```
const maxOffsetX = (imageRect.width - containerRect.width) / (2 * this.imageScale);
const maxOffsetY = (imageRect.height - containerRect.height) / (2 * this.imageScale);
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example or some fiddle so we could actually try out your example for ourselves?

Comment: @LajosArpad updated question with example in JSFiddle

Comment: You have some errors in the fiddle

Comment: Looks like you need to figure in the current scale factor in your max offset calculations - with `const maxOffsetX = (imageRect.width - containerRect.width) / 2 / this.imageScale; const maxOffsetY = (imageRect.height - containerRect.height) / 2 / this.imageScale;`, I think the fiddle is behaving as it should? https://jsfiddle.net/bzdwL914/

Comment: Alright, I made an answer out of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to figure in the current scale factor in your max offset calculations - with

```
const maxOffsetX = (imageRect.width - containerRect.width) / 2 / this.imageScale;
const maxOffsetY = (imageRect.height - containerRect.height) / 2 / this.imageScale;
```

it seems to behave as it should, see https://jsfiddle.net/bzdwL914/